# Cannot set a short value using "(expr)?<val1>:<val2>" notation in Java

Tags: java

I'm encountering a strange issue which I do not quite understand, but it's not a show-stopper for my program.  I am setting the value of a `short` variable based on the result of a conditional, and it works fine if I use a standard if/else but not if I use a shorthand conditional assignment.

Here's a simple example:

```
public class ShortTest {
    public static void main(String args []) {
        int i = 0;
        short s = 0;

        // This always works
        if( i < 100 )
            s = 0;
        else
            s = 1;

        // This causes an error
        s = (i < 100)?1:0;
    }
}
```

Compiling this code results in the following:

```
ShortTest.java:13: error: possible loss of precision
                s = (i < 100)?1:0;
                             ^
  required: short
  found:    int
1 error
```

But, if you add a cast to `short` to the `1`, `0`, or both, then it works fine.  All three of these statements will work:

`s = (i < 100)?(short)1:0;`

`s = (i < 100)?1:(short)0;`

`s = (i < 100)?(short)1:(short)0;`

It's not a big deal because the if/else is fine, but this is driving me nuts.  Is there a reason why these values can't be cast from `int` to `short` automatically when they're in a shorthand conditional?  And why does casting just one of them suddenly make the whole statement valid?  Any insights will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`1` and `0` are treat as literal `int` values here, and the result of this operation is an `int`, which cannot be narrowed by the compiler. You should add a cast explicitly:

```
s = (short) ((i < 100)? 1:0);
```

This is explained in [Java Language Specification. Chapter 15. Expressions. 15.25. Conditional Operator ?.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

> The conditional operator has three operand expressions. `?` appears between the first and second expressions, and `:` appears between the second and third expressions.
>
> (...)
>
> If both the second and the third operand expressions are numeric expressions, the conditional expression is a numeric conditional expression.
>
> (...)
>
> Numeric conditional expressions are standalone expressions (§15.2).
>
> The type of a numeric conditional expression is determined as follows:
>
> - **If the second and third operands have the same type, then that is the type of the conditional expression.**
> - If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.
> - If one of the operands is of type byte or Byte and the other is of type short or Short, then the type of the conditional expression is short.
> - **If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of type int whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.**
> - If one of the operands is of type T, where T is Byte, Short, or Character, and the other operand is a constant expression of type int whose value is representable in the type U which is the result of applying unboxing conversion to T, then the type of the conditional expression is U.
> - Otherwise, binary numeric promotion (§5.6.2) is applied to the operand types, and the type of the conditional expression is the promoted type of the second and third operands.
>
> <sub>Note that binary numeric promotion performs value set conversion (§5.1.13) and may perform unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).</sub>

Comment: Should also add a reference to the [specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25) which explains in detail what happens to various types.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  I'm curious, why does the casting of either value cause the entire thing to become valid?  If you cast one value to `short`, does it automatically mean that the conditional will only return that type (essentially the same thing as your solution)?

Comment: As the specs above state:  
If one of the operands is of type T where T is byte, short, or char, and the other operand is a constant expression (§15.28) of type int whose value is representable in type T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

Comment: @Dave added the necessary parts of the JLS 8. Ordous posted the link from JLS 7.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza thanks for the answer and for adding the details.  This is all very helpful.

Comment: @Dave note that JLS 8 provides a table to know how to apply these rules for primitive and wrapper types. JLS 7 doesn't provide it.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza but all is provided in the promotion rules! :) Anyway, thanks for pointing out there's a separate document for JLS8, I still live in the Java7 world.

Comment: @Ordous JLS 8 is more verbose than JLS 7 on this topic. If this is for better or not, will be decided by the readers.

Answer (score 0):

To add some details: As has been pointed out, integer literals always have type `int` (when there's no `L` suffix).  A statement like this:

```
s = 1;  // where s is short
```

therefore performs a narrowing conversion, from `int` to `short`.  Normally this kind of conversion isn't allowed automatically.  However, §5.2 of the JLS has some special rules that apply to constant expressions:

> In addition, if the expression is a constant expression (§15.28) of type byte, short, char, or int:
>
> - A narrowing primitive conversion may be used if the type of the variable is byte, short, or char, and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type of the variable.
> - A narrowing primitive conversion followed by a boxing conversion may be used if the type of the variable is:
>
>   - Byte and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type byte.
>   - Short and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type short.
>   - Character and the value of the constant expression is representable in the type char.

This means that this is also legal:

```
s = 1 + 2;
```

But unfortunately not this:

```
s = (i < 100) ? 1 : 0;
```

since the expression on the right doesn't meet the definition of a constant expression.  In theory, it would be possible for §5.2 to allow this case, by applying either to a constant expression **or** to a conditional expression where the second and third operands are both constant expressions (or conditional expressions that would be allowed, recursively).  Whether it's worthwhile to suggest this as a language change, I can't tell.